# Does Windows 7 Home Premium support Dual Core Processors?

Tags: windows-7, multi-processor

I'm looking to buy a new laptop (the new studio 14 from Dell). The processor for this laptop is an Intel Core i5-520M.

Think link http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-31012_7-10379487-10355804.html says that it supports only 1 CPU.

Also Dell recommend the Professionnal version even tough Home Premium is the default choice. So I'm a little confuse as does Windows 7 Home Premium support Dual Core Processors ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Physical CPUs, not Logical.

You can't have two ACTUAL processing units in the machine. Logical CPUs (cores) it supports more than one for sure.

Dell probably recommend professional because of the other features, and for a *laptop* I'd agree.

- Encrypting File System - Usefull to secure your sensative data if your laptop is stolen.
- Presentation Mode - For connecting to projection systems for mobile-meetings / presentations.
- Windows XP Mode - XP Virtual Machine for installing those apps that don't port up well.

Either way Home Premium should be fine for you.

Comment: Okay, I think I now understand. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: Also found that thread on msdn that confirms your answer : http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7hardware/thread/01bf018e-c1c4-4cb5-99fe-3091731080c9